# Rally Rest API - Returning false data

Tags: c#, rally

I am working with the `RallyRestApi` in .NET and am seeing some odd results. For example, I have a UserStory in rally with `FormattedID` = `Story4114`. When I execute this code, I expect to get nothing back, but I do.

```
public Boolean DoesArtifactExistInRally()
{
    var api = GetRallyApi();
    var request = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement")
    {
        Query = new Query("FormattedId", Query.Operator.Equals, "story41adasdabff14")
    };
    var result = api.Query(request);
    return result.TotalResultCount > 0;
}
```

Why does the Rally API think `Story4114` == `story41adasdabff14`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to .NET toolkit. If there is a story US123, a query on HierarchicalRequirement object in [Web Services API doc](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) using this query string:

```
(FormattedID = abc123)
```

will return US123. FormattedIDs are stored in a db as integers and that is the underlying reason for this undesired outcome.

Comment: So basically the query ignores the 'story' or 'task' prefix and just queries using the number?

Comment: That's correct - it queries the number and disregards the prefix.

Comment: Just after I posted this question, I discovered thats what it was probably doing. Thanks for the help.